# Alphanumeric 4 Digits Sequential Suffix Code

Tags: apex, trigger, class, automation

The project that I'm working now is to add a suffix 4 digits alphanumeric sequential code, to a part number, the suffix is starting with AAA0 and then AAA1, AAA2 and go on, this suffix it will be the same when the record contains the same attributes and is going to vary every time that part number is new and different to another one, so all part numbers are going to have this suffix as a part of this part number, in that way we can make this part number the same over the all database.

As the first step, I'm trying to avoid creating a bunch of records at this custom object, and my goal would be, generate this suffix every time that I need it, rather than input these suffix at once on this custom object, we are talking about of more than 175000 of records.

My question would be, how can I guarantee the sequentiality of this suffix? is there a way how to do it using a trigger?... I've tried to write some kind of code but I couldn't find the way how to keep the counters updated for the next sequential code.

The below code is creating all sequential 4 digits code an is working fine in AnonymousWindow.

```
string [] a = new string[] {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
string [] b = new string[] {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
string [] c = new string[] {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
string [] d = new string[] {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};

for(integer i=0; i<a.size(); i++)
    for(integer j=0; j<b.size(); j++)
        for(integer k=0; k<c.size(); k++)
            for(integer l=0; l<d.size(); l++)

                System.debug( a[i] + b[j] + c[k] + d[l]);
                System.debug( 'special==> '+a[1] + b[2] + c[3] + d[4]);
                System.debug( 'Total==> '+a.size()*b.size()*c.size()*d.size());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize a formula field along with an auto-number and the part number field. The auto number field will generate the sequence that you need to say AA1, and so on. The formula field should have the concatenated value of the part number and the auto number field, thus giving you the output as desired.

If you want to have the suffix appended to the part number directly, then you can still utilize the auto number field to generate the suffix with every save. Then utilize an after insert trigger/workflow field update or process builder to update the part number with the combination of existing part number and the auto number field.

Refer more on auto number on help article -- https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_field_types.htm&type=5